# Sequences of Real Numbers in a closed bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis

Why is it that a sequence in a closed, bounded interval [a, b] is a bounded sequence? What is the formal proof of this proposition from the definition of a bounded sequence?

Comment: The "closed" part is irrelevant: any sequence in *any* bounded interval is bounded. Proof: given any $t_n$ in the sequence, we have $a\leq t_n\leq b$, where $a$ and $b$ are the leftmost and rightmost bounds of the interval.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur: because I thought the question might be deleted or revised, because it's so obvious.

Comment: But the definition of a bounded sequence is not a≤tn≤b, where a and b are the leftmost and rightmost bounds of the interval. The definition of a bounded sequence is the absolute value of tn is less than some positive number M.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $[a, b]$. Then if $x_i, x_j \in [a, b]$, suppose WLOG that $x_i < x_j$. Then
\begin{align*}
|x_j - x_i| & = x_j - x_i \\
& \leq b - a
\end{align*}

Comment: But |xj−xi|≤b−a is not the definition of a bounded sequence. The definition of a bounded sequence is the absolute value of the sequence (not a difference of the terms of the sequence) is less than some positive number M.

Comment: There are a number of definitions of bounded. But you can check that your definition is satisfied for $M = \max \{ |a|, |b| \}$.